# Possible livestreaming with facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, live-streaming

Is it possible to start-stop a livestream in my own app using facebook's livestreaming API for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on Facebook's developer documentation shows that it is possible:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api